# enable shell escape with pandoc

Tags: latex, graphviz, pandoc

I'm trying to use the latex graphvis package in a pandoc markdown document. However it seems to require the `-shell-escape` flag be passed to latex. How can I enable `-shell-escape` on pandoc?

```
\digraph[scale=0.5]{MyGraph}{
Business -- Job;
Job -- Task;
Job -- User;
Job -- PayRate;
Task -- WorkSession;
User -- WorkSession;
PayRate -- WorkSession;
}
```

http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/03/25/embedding-graphviz-in-latex-documents

Comment: there is a pandoc filter that can convert graphviz code before latex conversion : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/pandocfilters/master/examples/graphviz.py ; might be easier, and works with every output format, and not only latex

Answer (score 10):

**pandoc** can now pass arguments directly to the LaTeX engine via the `--latex-engine-opt` flag. As an example, in order to pass the `-shell-escape` flag to `xelatex` you could do:

```
pandoc myfile.md -s -o myfile.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex --latex-engine-opt=-shell-escape
```

Comment: You should update your answer: a recent version of pandoc tells `--latex-engine-opt has been removed.  Use --pdf-engine-opt instead.`.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell pandoc to generate LaTeX, and then do whatever you want on the output.

```
pandoc -o mydocument.tex mydocument.md
pdflatex -shell-escape mydocument.tex
```

Pandoc has a `--latex-engine` option to tell it to run LaTeX differently, but this can only be a path to a program called `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`. If for some reason you want to be able to generate PDF from Markdown by calling `pandoc` directly, you can use a wrapper script.

```
pandoc --latex-engine=/path/to/pdflatex -o mydocument.pdf mydocument.md
```

where `/path/to/pdflatex` is executable and contains (assuming a Unix-like system)

```
#!/bin/sh
exec pdflatex -shell-escape "$@"
```